# Unable to rename folder in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I created a new folder in jupyter notebook which was given the default name "Untitled folder".

Upon trying to rename it to "my_folder", i get the following error

Rename failed

An error occurred while renaming "Untitled Folder" to "my_folder".

Permission denied: Untitled Folder

Answer (score 1):

The folder i was trying to rename was listed as a running notebook under the running tab.
after shutting it down, i was able to rename it.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the checkbox checked specific to the folder which you created and then use Rename from the top menu options.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of bug when renaming the file in jupyter notebook and I got rid of it by simply finding all files with the same name as the one causing the error and deleting them and creating a new one in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).